# Apache Kafka Producer Config: 'request.timeout.ms' VS. 'max.block.ms' properties

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

Given the below synchronous kafka producer

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("max.block.ms", 30000);
props.put("request.timeout.ms", 30000);
props.put("retries", 5);

KafkaProducer<String, byte[]> produce = new KafkaProducer<>(props);

//Send message
producer.send(producerRecord).get();
```

help me understand the difference between ***request.timeout.ms*** and ***max.block.ms*** producer configs. Does either include max time for all retries? Or does each retry have its own timeout?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

request.timeout.ms is used to timeout request, I would set this to the maximum time I can wait for the response.

max.block.ms is used for producer to block buffer time, serialization time etc.

For details look at this one.
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-19+-+Add+a+request+timeout+to+NetworkClient

Comment: request.timeout.ms(producer config) should be larger than replica.lag.time.max.ms(broker config) to reduce the possibility of message duplication due to producer retries. [Source](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs)

Answer (score 11):

I found the accepted answer a bit "thin", so may be this will help others.

There are two important things in your code:

```
KafkaProducer<String, byte[]> produce = new KafkaProducer<>(props);

//Send message
producer.send(producerRecord).get();
```

`producer.send(producerRecord)` - that is made from two parts : blocking and non-blocking. The blocking part is made from some "parts":

```
- Request metadata about brokers from zookeeper 
- Serialize message
- Choose a Partition 
- Place Message in the RecordAccumulator
```

Now, usually, the first three steps are fast (first one is cache after the initial call), while the fourth one might take time. It happens because `RecordAccumulator` has limited space (`buffer.memory`) and how much space you have there at the moment depends on the *other* thread in the producer client (called `Sender Thread`). If this thread is doing a bad job (retrieving and sending messages from `RecordAccumulator` to the brokers; there are metrics for all of this btw), your `send` method will be blocked (there is no space in the `RecordAccumulator`) until space becomes available.

All of these 4 steps are allowed to be blocked to a max of `max.block.ms`. And this is what the KIP means when it talks about:

- metadata fetch time (fetches metadata from zookeeper about brokers)
- buffer full block time (the time I was saying about)
- serialization time (customized serializer)
- partitioning time (customized partitioner)

---

There is also the `delivery.timeout.ms`. It's the total time to wait before the message is sent to the partition and it includes: time to push the record to a batch (in the `RecordAccumulator`) + time to get acks (for example `all` and wait for the message to be replicated across replicas) + time to send the message to the broker, including all retries, if any.

You can think about it as the time it takes from `send` method down to when it reaches all replicas and acks is sent back. All this time has to be *lower* than `delivery.timeout.ms`.

---

Before explaining `request.timeout.ms`, imho it's important to understand what `max.in.flight.requests.per.connection` is, because they are a little connected. Suppose that a batch is ready to be sent to the broker from the `RecordAccumulator` (either because its `batch.size` or `linger.ms` was fulfilled). If this batch is taken by the so-called "Sender Thread" (which is a thread in the client itself and is != the thread that calls `send` method) or not is defined by `max.in.flight.requests.per.connection`.

You can have as many as `max.in.flight.requests.per.connection` *concurrent* requests being active at any point in time. A slightly easier way to think about it is this. A "Sender Thread" has a certain loop that it constantly does, in pseudo-code:

```
while(true) {
    // check if there are batches to send
    // get the batches to send to the brokers
    // make requests to the broker
    // poll connections
    // etc
}
```

Suppose that this is the first batch to send. "Sender Thread" increments `max.in.flight.requests.per.connection` so that it becomes 1; gets the batches and sends it to the broker. It does *not* wait for an acknowledgment at this point in time, but goes back to its loop. So on, until it reaches 5 (default value for `max.in.flight.requests.per.connection`).

Now suppose there is batch to send to the broker, Sender Thread is not going to take since it has no available requests (we are at max 5 now). Instead it will "Poll Connections": it will ask the broker for the result of the previously sent [and the rest of the explanation is here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73900973/1059372)

---

With all this background it's time to look at `request.timeout.ms`, which is actually pretty easy now. When the client polls for connections - tries to get a response from the broker for each in flight request, it can do that within the `request.timeout.ms` (which by default is 30 seconds). This value is reset if we retry.

Answer (score 1):

So where is a place for retries and retry.backoff.ms?

When i tried to send request to broker/server that is turned off
(max.block.size = 60000, request.timeout.ms = 1000, delivery.timeout.ms = 2000, retries= 2, retry.backoff.ms = 100)

```
   try {
        kafkaTemplate.send(producerRecord).get();
    }catch (Exception e){
        LOGGER.error("Error while sending request: {}", e);
    }
```

**I get timeout after 60s -> max.block.ms**

Exception thrown:
**Send failed; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic DUMMY-TOPIC not present in metadata after 60000 ms.**

Does any retry is happening under the hood ?

Does timeout should appear earlier?  it Should take less then 7s -> delivery.timeout 2s for 3 times and backoff time is just 100 ms

Even if i set
kafkaTemplate.send(producerRecord).get(1000,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
It still waits to 60s -> max.block.ms till this method throws exception. Why the timeout exception was not for 1s.

Full props of producer:

```
    acks = 1
    batch.size = 16384
    bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9093]
    buffer.memory = 33554432
    client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
    client.id = DummyClient-1
    compression.type = none
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    delivery.timeout.ms = 2000
    enable.idempotence = false
    interceptor.classes = []
    key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
    linger.ms = 50
    max.block.ms = 60000
    max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5
    max.request.size = 6000000
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metadata.max.idle.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner
    receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 1000
    retries = 2
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    security.protocol = SSL
    security.providers = null
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    socket.connection.setup.timeout.max.ms = 30000
    socket.connection.setup.timeout.ms = 10000
```

Answer (score 0):

max.block.ms is also used to wait when fetching metadata.