# Understanding the max.inflight property of kafka producer

Tags: configuration, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, producer

I work on a bench of my Kafka cluster in version 1.0.0-cp1.

In part of my bench who focus on the max throughput possible with ordering guarantee and no data loss (a topic with only one partition), need I to set the `max.in.flight.requests.per.connection` property to `1`?

I've read [this article](https://medium.com/@felipedutratine/kafka-ordering-guarantees-99320db8f87f)
And I understand that I only have to set the max.in.flight to 1 if I enable the retry feature at my producer with the `retries` property.

Another way to ask my question: Only one partition + retries=0 (producer props) is sufficient to guarantee the ordering in Kafka?

I need to know because increase the max.in.flight increases drastically the throughput.

Comment: If you see the comments *in the bottom* you will see the correction from `max.in.flight.requests.per.connection` to `max.in.flight.requests.per.session`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your use case is slightly unclear. You mention ordering and no data loss but don't specify if you tolerate duplicate messages. So it's unclear if you want *At least Once* (QoS 1) or *Exactly Once*

Either way, as you're using 1.0.0 and only using a single partition, you should have a look at the Idempotent Producer instead of tweaking the Producer configs. It allows to properly and efficiently guarantee ordering and no data loss.

From the documentation:

> Idempotent delivery ensures that messages are delivered exactly once
> to a particular topic partition during the lifetime of a single
> producer.

The early Idempotent Producer was forcing `max.in.flight.requests.per.connection` to 1 (for the same reasons you mentioned) but in the latest releases it can now be used with `max.in.flight.requests.per.connection` set to up to 5 and still keep its guarantees.

Using the Idempotent Producer you'll not only get stronger delivery semantics (Exactly Once instead of At least Once) but it might even perform better!

I recommend you check the delivery semantics [in the docs]
[in the docs]:http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#semantics

---

Back to your question

Yes without the idempotent (or transactional) producer, if you want to avoid data loss (QoS 1) and preserve ordering, you have to set `max.in.flight.requests.per.connection`  to 1, allow `retries` and use `acks=all`. As you saw this comes at a significant performance cost.

Comment: I'm not sure you can set max.in.flight.requests.per.connection to 5 if you want to preserve message order. If one message is rejected and needs a retry but in the mid-time a second message has been dispatched and written to the topic the first message will be written in the topic after the second one. To avoid this scenario you can only have one message in flight. I understand you can set this property to 5 if you only want exacty-once delivery

Comment: @PabloAntequera : I don't know for former versions, but with recent versions of Kafka, enable.idempotence=true prevents Duplication & Keeps the ordering of the messages even if max.in.flight.requests.per.connection > 1. The explanations are here: https://docs.confluent.io/cloud/current/client-apps/optimizing/durability.html#duplication-and-ordering

Comment: does it keep the send sequence when send to different partitions per connection? I mean if one send failed, is it possible the later message will succeed.

Comment: if idempotency is not needed, in the producer, set max inflight to 1. Else use idempotency to true. In fact, idempotency to true should actually be more performant than max inflight = 1, plus it gives idempotency for free. The reason I think is, broker knows producer is working on idempotent session, so there is a seq number. If it finds a seq number is missing, it informs producer and stops processing messages. Producer then switches to max inflight = 1 temporarily.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you must set the `max.in.flight.requests.per.connection` property to `1`. 
In the article you have read it was an initial mistake (currently corrected) where author wrote:

> max.in.flights.requests.per.session

which doesn't exist in the Kafka documentation.

This errata comes probably from the book **"Kafka The Definitive Guide" (1st edition)** where you can read in the page 52:

> <...so if guaranteeing order is critical, we recommend setting
>   `in.flight.requests.per.session=1` to make sure that while a batch of
>   messages is retrying, additional messages will not be sent ...>

Answer (score 6):

imo, it is invaluable to also know about [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-5494) issue that makes things far more interesting and slightly more complicated.

When you enable `enable.idempotence=true` , every time you send a message to the broker, you also send a `sequence number`, starting from zero. Brokers store that sequence number too on their side. When you make a *next* request to the broker, let’s say with `sequence_id=3`, the broker can look at its currently stored sequence number and say :

- if its 4 - good, its a new batch of records
- if its 3 - its a duplicate
- if its 5 (or higher), it means messages were lost

And now `max.inflight.requests.per.connection` . A producer can send as many as this value *concurrent* requests without actually waiting for an answer from the broker. When we reach 3 (let’s say `max.inflight.requests.per.connection=3`) , we start to ask the broker for the previous results (at the same time we can’t process any batches now even if they are ready).

Now, for the sake of the example, let’s say the broker says this : “1 was OK, I stored it”, “2 has failed” and now the important part: because 2 failed, the only possible thing you can get for 3 is  “out of order”, which means it did not store it. The client now knows that it needs to reprocess `2` and `3` and it creates a List and resends them - in that exact order; if retry is enabled.

This explanation is probably over simplified, but this is my basic understanding after reading the source code a bit.

Comment: my understanding is the same as yours based on this https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/producer-configs.html#enable-idempotence, except that OPs question is for an older version of kafka right